# Undefined index error php wordpress plugin

Tags: php, debugging, wordpress

I tought its appropriate to post this here other than wordpress as my error is more related to php .

I am using addthissocial sign in plugin for social login for my website users .But when i try to embade the login buttons using the shortcut code given by the author of the plugin its not working and I cat see any login buttons .

when I try to debug using wp-debug and I got the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: addthis_signature in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/addthis-social-sign-in/addthis_social_sign_in.php on line 130

this is line 130 `if( $_REQUEST[ 'addthis_signature' ] != "" )`

How can I solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable"  and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, it is just a notice. You can solve it by adding a check like this:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST[ 'addthis_signature' ]) && $_REQUEST[ 'addthis_signature' ] != "" )
```

Comment: this is what the autor stated inside the plugin
copy and paste the tag <?php addthis_ssi();?> into your templates. Wherever you add them, a login button will appear.  But the login buttons are not appearing can you please help me.